# Shutdown doesn't fully turn the PC off

Tags: windows-8.1, shutdown

I have a desktop PC running Windows 8.1 with a 3570K, Asus P8Z77-V LE Plus motherboard, 4GB x 2 RAM, and a GTX 760 graphics card. After I tell the PC to shutdown, it will show "shutting down", the display turns off, but after that it will just stay on. However restarting the PC would allow it to fully turn off before turning back on.

It is my understanding that this issue is usually caused by the fast startup feature. Sadly, I've tried several things in that regard and others to no avail. Note that all the commands were used in an elevated command prompt including:

1. Shutting down from the start menu or Alt+F4 the desktop.
2. Using the `shutdown /s /f` command.
3. Accessing the registry and checking that the value of `HiberbootEnabled` which is located in "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE / SYSTEM / CurrentControlSet / Control / Session manager / Power" is set to `0`.
4. Disabling Hibernation entirely by using the command `powercfg.exe /hibernate off`
5. Using the `bcdedit /set disabledynamictick yes` command.
6. I did a clean Windows installation.
7. Used the "DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth" which returned the message `No component store corruption detected. The operation completed successfully` and followed it with `SFC /Scannow` multiple times. Each of which returned the message `Windows Resource Protection did not find any integrity violations`.

Note: Fast Startup tick box isn't showing in *Control Panel* -> *Power options* -> *Change what the power buttons do*.